# Why does my Moodle query work in "Ad hoc database queries" but not in my plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have the following query to retrieve academic advisers in a custom Moodle plugin.

The Academic adviser role is configured as defined here: https://docs.moodle.org/en/Parent_role

I have run it in *Ad hoc database queries* (and in MySQL Workbench), and it works fine in both of those, but for some bizarre reason it doesn't work in my plugin.

**In `db_update.php`:**

```
function get_academic_advisees($userid) {
    global $DB;

    $sql = 'SELECT child.username, child.firstname, child.lastname
            FROM {user} user
            JOIN {role_assignments} ra ON ra.userid = user.id
            JOIN {role} role ON role.id = ra.roleid
            JOIN {context} ctx ON ctx.id = ra.contextid 
            AND ctx.contextlevel = 30
            JOIN {user} child ON child.id = ctx.instanceid
            WHERE role.shortname = "academic_adviser"
            and user.username = ?';

    return $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($userid));
}
```

**In my `attendance_form.php` page, which is included in `attendance.php` (which calls `db_update.php`):**

```
require_once("{$CFG->libdir}/formslib.php");

class attendance_form extends moodleform {

    function definition() {
        $mform =& $this->_form;

        $mform->addElement('html', '<h2>' . get_string('attendance', 'local_attendance')  . '</h2>');
        $mform->addElement('html', '<p>This report allows you to retrieve attendance data for your academic advisees.</p>');

        //$mform->addElement('text', 'student_number', get_string('student_number', 'local_attendance'));
        global $USER;
        $userid = $USER->id;
        $myAdvisees = array();
        $adviseeArray = array();
        $myAdvisees = get_academic_advisees($userid);
        foreach($myAdvisees as $myAdvisee) {
            $key = $myAdvisee->username;
            $value = $myAdvisee->firstname . $myAdvisee->lastname . '(' . $myAdvisee->username . ')';
            $adviseeArray[$key] = $value;
        }

        $mform->addElement('select', 'student_number', get_string('student_number', 'local_attendance'), $adviseeArray);

        $this->add_action_buttons(true, get_string('save', 'local_attendance'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function takes a param 'userid', but in the query it tries to match this to 'user.username'.

So, you need to put:

```
$userid = $USER->username;
```

If you want it to work in your form.

Also, please remove the & from $mform =& $this->_form - Moodle stopped supporting PHP 4 a long time ago!

Comment: Thank you so much  - I was passing it $USER->id so it should have been `and user.id = ?`

Answer (score 0):

So the correct code is (with thanks to @davosmith):

```
function get_academic_advisees($userid) {
    global $DB;

    $sql = 'SELECT child.username, child.firstname, child.lastname
            FROM {user} user
            JOIN {role_assignments} ra ON ra.userid = user.id
            JOIN {role} role ON role.id = ra.roleid
            JOIN {context} ctx ON ctx.id = ra.contextid 
            AND ctx.contextlevel = 30
            JOIN {user} child ON child.id = ctx.instanceid
            WHERE role.shortname = "academic_adviser"
            and user.id = ?';

    return $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($userid));
}
```

Comment: Minor note - if you want this to be compatible with different database backends (important for core Moodle, probably less important for your site), you should use single quotes ' to contain strings, so that should be:
role.shortname = 'academic_advisor'

Comment: thanks - at some point I had the $sql enclosed in double quotes and the string enclosed in single quotes, and ended up swapping it round